# example not working - bind.cols using plyrmr

Tags: r, hadoop

Why does this simple block of code not work using [`plyrmr`](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/plyrmr)?

```
input(mtcars) %|%
  group(gear) %|%
  bind.cols(obs = seq(from=1,to=nrow()))
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the mistake,

I should have included a reference to the pipe as follows:

```
input(mtcars) %|%
  group(gear) %|%
  bind.cols(obs = seq(from=1,to=nrow(.data)))
```

Where `.data` is a reference / call to the pipe generated by the `group` call